# Reference request: Gauge theory

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, gauge-theory

What are some good introductory texts to gauge theory? I have some basic differential geometry knowledge, but I don’t know any algebraic geometry.

Also, as a side question, what intuitively is a gauge field, and what are the Yang Mills equations saying?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85343/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [References for classical Yang-Mills theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85343/references-for-classical-yang-mills-theory)

Answer (score 5):

Two texts by Donaldson: [Mathematical aspects of gauge theory](https://www.lsgnt-cdt.ac.uk/assets/8h00svqzffcqd97tf8oxcokv199scmjb.pdf), [Mathematical uses of Gauge theory](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~skdona/EMP.PDF). I think the notion of Ehresmann connection (= gauge field, basically a field of horizontal subspaces) is fairly intuitive itself, and the Yang-Mills equations are the Euler-Lagrange equations associated to the Yang-Mills functional (which is a kind of energy functional, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199144/yang-mills-functional-and-energy)). So in a sense the solutions to the Y-M equations minimise energy.

Comment: These are definitely not *introductory* texts, as the OP is asking for.

Comment: @AlexM. I think what is introductory is in the eye of the beholder. I knew nothing about gauge theory (just some basic differential geometry, which of course includes connections)  when I started reading the first one, and I could follow it fairly well. They are notes written for graduate students.